# JPQL to query java.util.Date field of entity using date portion of date time

Tags: java, mysql, jpql

I have an entity with a date field (java.util.Date). Normally the date is saved as for example `2012-10-19 21:29:03.000`. My database is MySQL.

Now I need to query the database, through JPQL, using strictly the date portion, i.e., `2012-10-19`. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

That can be done by giving TemporalType when setting parameter:

```
Date param ...
Query q = em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM EntityA a WHERE a.someDate > :param");
q.setParameter("param", param, TemporalType.DATE);
```